# Getting through the DOM from the file to which I did a post request through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, dom, post, request

I used this simplify examples to explain better the question.

given the following post request under ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(#submit).click(function()
   {
    $var = $("#result");
    $code = $("#code"); 
    $.post("ajax.php", {option : $var, code: $code}, function()
   {
     //Getting through the DOM could be useful if you want to analyse the answer coming from the ajax.php file
      var $DOMresponse = getElementByTagName("div")[0].firstChild.data; // I would want the correct code here because this is incorrect... this is ti give you an idea
      if($DOMresponse == "your code is correct")
      {
        $("#container1").fadeOut(400, function(){ $("#container1").html(result); });
        $("#container1").fadeIn();
      }
      elseif($DOMresponse == "your code is incorrect. Go again trough the procedure")
      {
        $("#container2").fadeOut(400, function(){ $("#container2").html(result); });
        $("#container2").fadeIn();
      }
       // In this second case I could fill the second container id="container2"
    });
  });
});
```

ajax.php example:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['request']==1)
 { 
     if($_POST['code']==$user['code'])
     {
       ?><img src="...">
         <div>tomatoes</div>
         <div>potatoes</div>
         <div id="answer">your code is correct</div> <?php 
     } 
     else
     {
       ?><img src="...">
         <div>apples</div>
         <div>oranges</div>
         <div>your code is incorrect. Go again trough the procedure</div> <?php
      }
 }
```

I would like to know how to get through the DOM of the ajax.php file.

how do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this before inserting the result to the page? If so create new element and insert the result to it. For example

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var obj = $(div).html(response);
```

Now you have a standard jQuery object with the dom element.

Responding to the comment:

I am confused. Do you want to validate the code in php or js? It looks like your checking if what is send through post is the same as defined in $user variable. So validating the code is done in php. In that case wouldn't be simpler to use json as a response. In php script create result array with key status set to 1 or 0. In post resposne you can check response.status == 0.

Other wise it look just strange that you make the validation once in php and the twice in js after response. Besides if you set your response to be standard text then you have to create dom element and place the reponse inside to be able to search through it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't need to do what you are saying... I need to get through the DOM in order to recognize the response "your code is correct" or "your code is incorrect" within the javascript. because what you both guys are advising->The javascript does not recognize the response, the javascript is only taking and giving an answer without analysis or ckecking. How do you do this?

Comment: I changed a bit the example to explain better what I wanted to ask! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is how do you get the value of $('#code') in the ajax.php file.

Here's what you're doing:

```
  var $code = $('#code'); // jQuery object
  $.post('ajax.php', { code: $code });
```

The problem with this is that you're passing the entire jQuery object to ajax.php. What you probably want to do is pass the value or html of the $('#code') object, like so:

```
  var code = $('#code').html(); // if it's a non-input element
  var code = $('#code').val(); // if it's an input
  $.post('ajax.php', { code: code });
```

Then in the ajax.php file, your $_POST['code'] will equal the value of code (e.g. "ABC123"), which you can then use to compare with $user['code'] or whatever you want.

I hope I understand the problem correctly. Good luck.

EDIT: I think I understand what you're getting at now. What you want to do is this:

HTML:

Javascript:

```
    var $option = 'request';
    var $code = $('#code').val();
    $.post('ajax.php', { option: $option, code: $code }, function(data) {
        if (data == 'valid') {
             // show valid code result here
        } else {
             // show invalid code result here
        }
    });
```

and ajax.php

```
    <? if ($_POST['option'] == 'request') {
          if ($_POST['code'] == '123ABC') {
              echo 'valid';
          } else {
              echo 'invalid';
          }
       }
    ?>
```

Notice that the variable *data* comes from the function(data) part in the $.post parameter. That *data* variable contains the response from ajax.php (in my example, it would be 'valid'.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no. I want to get through the DOM... something like var response = getElementsByTagName("div")[0].firstChild.data; and then the output would be "your code is correct" or "your code is incorrect". In need to get through the DOM... this is a simplified example so don't search the logic in here.

Comment: I changed a bit the example to explain better what I wanted to ask! Thanks

Comment: Well almost.. in your example you do not deal with several divs or html tag elements, you ve just tripped them. Thats going trhough the DOM means... the answer request is not only a string... could be several divs, and therefore i am looking for a way to locate a concrete  div or,and concrete answer in this div. I updated my example again.